# Check string inside column wrong behaviour - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame ({
    'Name':['Unable host=test1, status=c0000192','Unable host=test2, status=22228001','Unable host=test3, status=c000018d'],
    'Error':['NaN','NaN','NaN']
    })


print(df)
                                   Name Error
0  Unable host=test1, status=c0000192   NaN
1  Unable host=test2, status=22228001   NaN
2  Unable host=test3, status=c000018d   NaN
```

The code should follow the below if statements:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame ({
    'Name':['Unable host=test1, status=c0000192','Unable host=test2, status=22228001','Unable host=test3, status=c000018d'],
    'Error':['NaN','NaN','NaN']
    })

if df['Name'].str.contains('status=c000018d').any():
    df['Error'] = 'Trust Failure'

elif df['Name'].str.contains('status=22228001').any():
    df['Error'] = 'No creds'

else:
    df['Error'] = 'Other'

print(df)
```

The output should be:

```
                                   Name          Error
0  Unable host=test1, status=c0000192  Other
1  Unable host=test2, status=22228001  No creds
2  Unable host=test3, status=c000018d  Trust Failure
```

Instead, I get:

```
                                   Name          Error
0  Unable host=test1, status=c0000192  Trust Failure
1  Unable host=test2, status=22228001  Trust Failure
2  Unable host=test3, status=c000018d  Trust Failure
```

Why is this happening? It's like the first if statement matches everything.

Comment: Your issue here is the use of `any()` it is working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are mixing things here, try this way:

```
df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains('status=c000018d'), 'Error'] = 'Trust Failure'
df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains('status=22228001'), 'Error'] = 'No creds'
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'NaN', 'Error'] = 'Other'
```

What you are doing returns true in the first if statement and fill all values with 'Trust Failure'.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

[`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) suits for this problem, which is a vectorized method for a multi-conditional column:

```
conditions = [df['Name'].str.contains('status=c000018d'), 
              df['Name'].str.contains('status=22228001')]
df['Error'] = np.select(conditions, choices=['Trust Failure', 'No creds'], default='Other')

                                 Name          Error
0  Unable host=test1, status=c0000192          Other
1  Unable host=test2, status=22228001       No creds
2  Unable host=test3, status=c000018d  Trust Failure
```

Comment: Great solution, I didn't know np.select could suit for this case